# Grid exporting excel file without headers

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to build a small program which export multiple grid record in one excel sheet, the code below saves the data from all three gridview and export them but the problem is it only shows the header for the first gridview and adds the records for rest of the two grid like they are on a single table.

The Record m trying to export looks like this,

[image]

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel()
    ' Creating a Excel object.
    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
    Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing

    Try

        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

        worksheet.Name = "Roster Details"

        Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1
        Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1

        'Loop through each row and read value from each column.
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayed.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayed.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex = 1 Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayed.Columns(j).HeaderText
                Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayed.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvNotPlayed.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgvNotPlayed.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex <> 1 Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvNotPlayed.Columns(j).HeaderText
                    'Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvNotPlayed.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayerPlayedSchedule.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayerPlayedSchedule.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex = 1 Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayerPlayedSchedule.Columns(j).HeaderText
                Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayerPlayedSchedule.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayerNotPlayedSchedule.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayerNotPlayedSchedule.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex = 1 Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayerNotPlayedSchedule.Columns(j).HeaderText
                Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayerNotPlayedSchedule.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next


        'Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
        Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
        saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2

        If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)
            MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        excel.Quit()
        workbook = Nothing
        excel = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

The result its generating is somewhat like this,

[image]

What I am aiming for is somewhat similar to this thing.

[image]

If I headerRow = cellRowIndex + 1 for this part of the code then the result looks like this.

```
 'next  section header row
        headerRow = cellRowIndex + 1

        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvNotPlayed.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgvNotPlayed.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex <> headerRow Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvNotPlayed.Columns(j).HeaderText
                    'Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvNotPlayed.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next
```

[image]
I will really greatfull if someone can help me solve this problem.

Best Regards

SMHasnain

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code re-setting the header row (it's row()=1 only fore the first data set):

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel()
    ' Creating a Excel object.
    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application()
    Dim workbook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)
    Dim worksheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet = Nothing

    Try

        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet

        worksheet.Name = "Roster Details"

        Dim cellRowIndex As Integer = 1
        Dim cellColumnIndex As Integer = 1

        'Loop through each row and read value from each column.
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayed.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayed.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex = 1 Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayed.Columns(j).HeaderText
                Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayed.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

'next  section header row
headerRow = cellRowIndex + 1

        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvNotPlayed.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgvNotPlayed.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex <> headerRow  Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvNotPlayed.Columns(j).HeaderText
                    'Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvNotPlayed.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

'next  section header row
headerRow = cellRowIndex + 1

        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayerPlayedSchedule.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayerPlayedSchedule.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex = headerRow  Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayerPlayedSchedule.Columns(j).HeaderText
                Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayerPlayedSchedule.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next

 'next  section header row
headerRow = cellRowIndex + 1 

        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayerNotPlayedSchedule.Rows.Count - 2
            For j As Integer = 0 To dgvPlayerNotPlayedSchedule.Columns.Count - 1
                ' Excel index starts from 1,1. As first Row would have the Column headers, adding a condition check.
                If cellRowIndex = headerRow  Then
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayerNotPlayedSchedule.Columns(j).HeaderText
                Else
                    worksheet.Cells(cellRowIndex, cellColumnIndex) = dgvPlayerNotPlayedSchedule.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString()
                End If
                cellColumnIndex += 1
            Next
            cellColumnIndex = 1
            cellRowIndex += 1
        Next


        'Getting the location and file name of the excel to save from user.
        Dim saveDialog As New SaveFileDialog()
        saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        saveDialog.FilterIndex = 2

        If saveDialog.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName)
            MessageBox.Show("Export Successful")
        End If
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        excel.Quit()
        workbook = Nothing
        excel = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: on which part I should add that reset code, can u guide me more.

Comment: This will set the new header row for the 2nd and 3rd section: headerRow = cellRowIndex + 1 (it's in the code snippet in my answer)

Comment: @MHHasnain don't forget to upvote and accept answers that have helped!

Comment: If i add headerRow = cellRowIndex +1 then it still shows the first only, what it does is it clear records from the excel file. I dont know how to show image on this comment section otherwise I would have uploaded it here. wait let me update the post above.